# How to parse a Javascript +random Number into .style.backgroundImage URL

Tags: javascript, css

**Hi, I would like to get your opinion about this example.**
*Considering me as a beginner of coding.*

I would like to add a random number after the URL GIF-File-Name.

Ex.:
Turn **"intro_animation.gif"** into **"intro_animation.gif?v=7463"** The number at the end should be random each time the browser refreshes, so the animated GIF can start again from the beginning.

I've seen many similar examples on stackoverflow.com, but I dont know how to put the parts together

...

Here is my code, which obviously don't work.
I want it to keep it as simple a possible.

```
<script>
setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById("intro").style.backgroundImage = "url('./anim/intro_animation.gif' + ?v= + (Math.random() * 1000); )";
}, 0);
</script>

<div id="intro" class="intro_animation_gif" style="background-image: url('./anim/intro_animation.gif');">
</div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking, especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". Then edit your question appropriately if you would like some help.

Comment: A bit offtopic: are you using `setTimeout` because you want to somehow wait for the intro element to load? If that's the case you could use the widespread method of putting your script right before `</body>` which guarantees that all elements are loaded when the script is executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not too far off. Make sure you put double quotes around the parts that are strings and concatenate with pluses.

You might also want to round the random number to make sure it does not contain decimals.

Sample:

```
document.getElementById("intro").style.backgroundImage = 
    "url('./anim/intro_animation.gif?v=" + Math.round((Math.random() * 1000)) + "')";
```

Comment: Solved!
Thank you ACJ!